# Variant of "Ansible lineinfile adds duplicate line"

Tags: ansible

I am trying to get ansible to configure unattended upgrades in ubuntu. Unfortunately I get duplicate lines when running the role multiple times.

Here is my code:

```
- name: apt | Configure unattended-upgrades
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades
    regexp: "{{ item }}"
    line: "{{ harden_linux_unattended_upgrades_settings[item] }}"
    state: present
  with_items:
      - "{{ harden_linux_unattended_upgrades_settings | list }}"
```

and

```
harden_linux_unattended_upgrades_settings:
    "^Unattended-Upgrade::Mail": 'Unattended-Upgrade::Mail "{{ ubuntu_common_email }}";'
    "^Unattended-Upgrade::MailReport": 'Unattended-Upgrade::MailReport "on-change";' # later if working set to "only-on-error"
    "^Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Kernel-Packages": 'Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Kernel-Packages "true";'
    "^Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies": 'Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies "true";'
    "^Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot": 'Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true";'
    "^Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time": 'Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time "2:50";'
```

The result when running it is that it works fine the first time. Every time after that I get this result and (weirdly only some) duplicate lines:

```
changed: [cloud-host] => (item=^Unattended-Upgrade::Mail)
changed: [cloud-host] => (item=^Unattended-Upgrade::MailReport)
ok: [cloud-host] => (item=^Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Kernel-Packages)
ok: [cloud-host] => (item=^Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies)
changed: [cloud-host] => (item=^Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot)
changed: [cloud-host] => (item=^Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time)
```

with this at the end of the file:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Mail "john@doe.com";
Unattended-Upgrade::Mail "john@doe.com";
Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Kernel-Packages "true";
Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies "true";
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true";
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true";
Unattended-Upgrade::Mail "john@doe.com";
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true";
Unattended-Upgrade::Mail "john@doe.com";
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true";
Unattended-Upgrade::Mail "john@doe.com";
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true";
Unattended-Upgrade::MailReport "on-change";
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time "2:50";
```

I have seen many threads with problems with duplicate lines but I can't identify my problem there. In particular I don't understand why this seems to work with

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Kernel-Packages
```

and

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies
```

I just don't see any difference to the other lines..

---

**Edit:**
Thanks for the very helpful answer! This is what I ended up with (I changed other parts as well):

```
- name: apt | Configure unattended-upgrades
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades
    regexp: "^{{ item }}\\s"
    line: '{{ item }} "{{ harden_linux_unattended_upgrades_settings[item] }}";'
    state: present
  with_items:
      - "{{ harden_linux_unattended_upgrades_settings | list }}"
```

and

```
harden_linux_unattended_upgrades_settings:
    "Unattended-Upgrade::Mail": "{{ ubuntu_common_email }}"
    "Unattended-Upgrade::MailReport": "on-change" # later if working set to "only-on-error"
    "Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Kernel-Packages": "true"
    "Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies": "true"
    "Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot": "true"
    "Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time": "2:50"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have :

```
    "^Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot": 'Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true";'
    "^Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time": 'Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time "2:50";'
```

the first regex `^Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot` matches both: `Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot` and `Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time`.

so the second time, it does the following:

- match `Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot` and do nothing
- match `Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time` and replace it by `Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot`
- since there is no `Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time` anymore, it adds it back

so now, you have 2 `Automatic-Reboot` and 1 `Automatic-Reboot-Time`

same logic for `Unattended-Upgrade::Mail` and `Unattended-Upgrade::Mail-Report`

you can improve you regex by matching the following  `"`